# Ошибка A1 NO Uncorrect mailhost при подключении к почте outlook через javaMail

Tags: java, imap, javamail, pop3

> Необходимо загрузить почту с корпоративного ящика. Пробовал
>   использовать как IMAP, так и POP3 - всегда возникает одно и то же
>   исключение. При этом логин и пароль верные. Всегда возникает почему-то
>   именно эта ошибка. Версия самая последняя - 1.5.6

Меня смущает конкретно вот эта строчка

```
`DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO Uncorrect mailHost "XXXX" for mailbox userName`
```

Так как XXXX - несколько иной адрес. Если вместо XXXX был `mail.outlook.com`, то в ошибке на месте ХХХХ стоит email.outlook.com

**Stack trace:**

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.6
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "XXX", port 143, isSSL false
* OK IMAP4 ready
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS AUTH=PLAIN STARTTLS
A0 OK completed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host="XXX", user=userName, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO Uncorrect mailHost "XXXX" for mailbox userName
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Uncorrect mailHost "XXXX" for mailbox userName
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:725)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at main.Folders.main(Folders.java:108)
```

Запуск произвожу из демо-примера

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import com.sun.mail.imap.*;

/**
 * Demo app that exercises the Message interfaces.
 * List information about folders.
 *
 * @author John Mani
 * @author Bill Shannon
 */

public class folderlist {
    static String protocol = null;
    static String host = null;
    static String user = null;
    static String password = null;
    static String url = null;
    static String root = null;
    static String pattern = "%";
    static boolean recursive = false;
    static boolean verbose = false;
    static boolean debug = false;

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
    int optind;
    for (optind = 0; optind < argv.length; optind++) {
        if (argv[optind].equals("-T")) {
        protocol = argv[++optind];
        } else if (argv[optind].equals("-H")) {
        host = argv[++optind];
        } else if (argv[optind].equals("-U")) {
        user = argv[++optind];
        } else if (argv[optind].equals("-P")) {
        password = argv[++optind];
        } else if (argv[optind].equals("-L")) {
        url = argv[++optind];
        } else if (argv[optind].equals("-R")) {
        root = argv[++optind];
        } else if (argv[optind].equals("-r")) {
        recursive = true;
        } else if (argv[optind].equals("-v")) {
        verbose = true;
        } else if (argv[optind].equals("-D")) {
        debug = true;
        } else if (argv[optind].equals("--")) {
        optind++;
        break;
        } else if (argv[optind].startsWith("-")) {
        System.out.println(
      "Usage: folderlist [-T protocol] [-H host] [-U user] [-P password] [-L url]");
        System.out.println(
    "\t[-R root] [-r] [-v] [-D] [pattern]");
        System.exit(1);
        } else {
        break;
        }
    }
    if (optind < argv.length)
        pattern = argv[optind];

    // Get a Properties object
    Properties props = System.getProperties();

    // Get a Session object
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    session.setDebug(debug);

    // Get a Store object
    Store store = null;
    Folder rf = null;
    if (url != null) {
        URLName urln = new URLName(url);
        store = session.getStore(urln);
        store.connect();
    } else {
        if (protocol != null)
        store = session.getStore(protocol);
        else
        store = session.getStore();

        // Connect
        if (host != null || user != null || password != null)
        store.connect(host, user, password);
        else
        store.connect();
    }

    // List namespace
    if (root != null)
        rf = store.getFolder(root);
    else
        rf = store.getDefaultFolder();

    dumpFolder(rf, false, "");
    if ((rf.getType() & Folder.HOLDS_FOLDERS) != 0) {
        Folder[] f = rf.list(pattern);
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
        dumpFolder(f[i], recursive, "    ");
    }

    store.close();
    }

    static void dumpFolder(Folder folder, boolean recurse, String tab)
                    throws Exception {
    System.out.println(tab + "Name:      " + folder.getName());
    System.out.println(tab + "Full Name: " + folder.getFullName());
    System.out.println(tab + "URL:       " + folder.getURLName());

    if (verbose) {
        if (!folder.isSubscribed())
        System.out.println(tab + "Not Subscribed");

        if ((folder.getType() & Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES) != 0) {
        if (folder.hasNewMessages())
            System.out.println(tab + "Has New Messages");
        System.out.println(tab + "Total Messages:  " +
                        folder.getMessageCount());
        System.out.println(tab + "New Messages:    " +
                        folder.getNewMessageCount());
        System.out.println(tab + "Unread Messages: " +
                        folder.getUnreadMessageCount());
        }
        if ((folder.getType() & Folder.HOLDS_FOLDERS) != 0)
        System.out.println(tab + "Is Directory");

        /*
         * Demonstrate use of IMAP folder attributes
         * returned by the IMAP LIST response.
         */
        if (folder instanceof IMAPFolder) {
        IMAPFolder f = (IMAPFolder)folder;
        String[] attrs = f.getAttributes();
        if (attrs != null && attrs.length > 0) {
            System.out.println(tab + "IMAP Attributes:");
            for (int i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++)
            System.out.println(tab + "    " + attrs[i]);
        }
        }
    }

    System.out.println();

    if ((folder.getType() & Folder.HOLDS_FOLDERS) != 0) {
        if (recurse) {
        Folder[] f = folder.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
            dumpFolder(f[i], recurse, tab + "    ");
        }
    }
    }
}
```